# How can I compare 2 CSS files to see if they are *semantically* identical?

Tags: css, text, sass

I am refactoring some SCSS code, and want to make sure that the generated CSS code does not change *semantically*, even if it changes *literally*. The refactoring consists of creating a mixin and replacing a code fragment duplicated in many places with an include of the mixin.

The problem is that in some of the places attribute `a` was listed before attribute `b`, but in other places it was the reverse. Using the mixin of course produces a consistent order for all uses of it. So a simple text comparison produces a difference that I don't want it to.

For example, if I start out with this code:

```
.foo {
  background: white;
  color: brown;
}

.bar {
  color: brown;
  background: white;
}
```

...and then refactor it to:

```
@mixin my-colors {
  background: white;
  color: brown;
}

.foo {
  @include my-colors
}

.bar {
  @include my-colors
}
```

..then the generated text for `.bar` will change, even though the attributes as an unordered set did not. In other words, a text comparison will show that the CSS has changed when in fact it semantically has not.

Is there a way to compare the files such that these inconsistent orders can be ignored?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a program.  If you stick attributes into arrays for the before version, and subtract attributes from the array in the after version, a non-logically changed class would result in an empty array.  Too easy in Ruby!

Comment: I thought that would work too, but it was pointed out to me (see the thread at https://twitter.com/keithrbennett/status/1181246561101049856) that order sometimes *does* matter. The case of duplicate attribute specifications is another situation where order would matter.

Comment: so, I was focusing on the part where you asked "Is there a way to compare the files such that these inconsistent orders can be ignored?"  You seem to now be saying that you need to know where there are inconsistent orders.  And perhaps further, that there is no way to refactor inconsistent orders.  So are you basically asking for a list of things you can't do anything about?

Comment: Yes, you addressed my original question, and thank you for that. I don't agree with your conclusion that the problem is not solvable. It _is_ solvable, it just requires more intelligence/work than I thought. For example, the normalization process could check for duplicates and ensure that the normalized form contained them in the same order.

Answer (score -2):

There are several ways to do that. If you are using a code editor such as Notepad++ it has a function to compare two opened filed. Every code editor has that. There are even online tools that can compare two texts/codes such as https://www.diffchecker.com.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. A text comparison is not sufficient. I mentioned that later in the question, but I just edited the first sentence of the question to make that more obvious.